# Toggle Flash With Javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, video, memory-leaks

The site I'm currently working on has a series of videos on a carousel (6 altogether). As you could guess, this is causing us/me some performance headaches, especially regarding the flash-video version.

To help with the CPU usage, I began calling .hide() (we're using jQuery) on the videos as they leave the focus of the carousel. That helped the CPU a lot by itself.

**The problem is, each time I call .show() on the object element, I notice an XHR for the video source in Fiddler.** I believe this new resource is getting added to memory each time, because I'm seeing a memory leak. I've also tried removing/recreating the element, but I experience the same type of memory leak as with hiding and showing the video.

I've also looked into writing Javascript hooks into the flash file with ActionScript, but I don't have that kind of environment setup, so I'm looking for something strictly javascript.

**Is there an effective way to pause/play the video?**

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to tell a Flash video to stop using a purely Javascript solution. If you had access to the Actionscript source, you could listen for an ExternalInterface callback and handle the pausing code.

As for destroying and recreating a Flash object via Javascript, if you are using SWFObject you could try the removeSWF method. It will remove the whole object tag from the source, but I'm not certain what the memory management in the browser looks like. You may face the same memory leak situation as before.

My suggestion would be to try and get access to the Flash source or write your own so that you can handle the pause and resume functionality properly.